# How to scroll to the particular div on button click in a single page application using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

Iam having two buttons(Home, Contact Us) in my header and iam having the content for "Home and Contact Us" in a div on the same page, while im clicking the home or contact button it should scroll to that particular div using **React-Router**
Since iam new to these concepts i can't find a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Why you want `React-Router` for this?**

Can't you directly wrap the buttons into `<a>` tag and provide a `href` attribute to `<a>` tag with the `id` of section where you want to scroll.

**e.g.**

```
<a href="#home"><button>Home</button></a>
```

Somewhere in you component,

```
<div id="home">
...
</div>
```

For smooth scrolling effect you can add this css,

```
html{scroll-behavior:smooth}
```

**Updated**

On the basis of comment, you can make use of [`react-router-hash-link`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link).

```
yarn add react-router-hash-link
or
npm install --save react-router-hash-link
```

// In YourComponent.js

```
...
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';
...
```

// Use it just like a RRv4  (to can be a string or an object, see RRv4 api for details):

```
<Link to="/some/path#with-hash-fragment">Link to Hash Fragment</Link>
```

Comment: Actually that's my requirement sir, I am using reactjs for view and i have two buttons namely contact and about, while im clicking on those buttons it should scroll to that particular div and the url should also change..